# Any recommended approach to location picking in iOS?

Tags: ios, dictionary

Are there any examples/recommended approaches for implementing a location picker (for want of a better term) in iOS?

The high level goal is for a user to be able to select from within an app a location that I can then later redisplay on a map. This location may not be related to the current location of the user.

Abstractly, it seems like the thing to do is to present them with a map kit map that includes a search box. They'd either search a la google maps or drop a pin. When they've identified a location, they use some kind of done button to get back to the rest of the app.

I haven't seen anything like this and my map kit foo is pretty weak ...

Comment: One -1 ... too general? I'm hoping for concrete responses, along the lines of either "can't be done" or "use this mapkit class this way ..."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is pretty much what I was looking for:

http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/252784277/mapkit-annotation-drag-and-drop-with-callout-info

It doesn't have the search/geocoding stuff, but that's fairly easy compared to the low-level pin/CA stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to get familiar with geocoding and reverse geocoding in Map Kit. Your question is quite broad, but the geocoding examples would be where I'd start.

Comment: Thanks. The actual geocoding stuff is fairly straightforward. It's really the "picker" side of things I don't have a handle on. I'd like something like UIDatePicker for maps: give it an initial location and have it handle pan, zoom, search, and pin drop. As far as I can tell, nothing like that exists. Maybe nobody's done it?